# How to clone private BitBucket repository in GitHub desktop app

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I successfully cloned my private BitBucket repository into the GitHub desktop app, however due to some problems I had to re-install GitHub completely which means I have to clone the repository again. Unfortunately I cannot remember how I did it before and I have tried almost all the instructions I could find through multiple searches.

Supposedly all I had to do was drag and drop the HTTPS clone link of my repository, which appears to work but eventually the sync progress stays stuck and after a long time it errors out, probably because it is a private repository, not public.

How can I clone my private BitBucket repository in my GitHub desktop app?

EDIT: The problem met before was related to file corruption which I discovered on the BitBucket side which is why no matter what I tried it would never work. I'm afraid I haven't found a solution for this so I ended up creating a new repo because I the previous one was still young.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If git clone *your repository* doesn't work than just download your repository

```
https://bitbucket.org/Yourname/yourproject/downloads
```

Unzip it and than link it to the remote by running git init and git remote add origin

Comment: I asked how to do it in my GitHub app, not through a terminal.

Comment: Also your method does not work. Once I try to publish through the app it tries to sync and then nothing happens, goes back to the previous "publish" button. Neither the SSH or HTTPS clone links worked. Remember that this is a private repo.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is a private repository

Comment: It looks like the file corruption took place on BitBucket side, I have tried using SourceTree with the console opened and it showed quite a few errors while syncing files before failing. I'll select yours as an answer because the question isn't fully correct to begin with.